# How to update a SQL Server table by replacing a number with NULL value and auto increment the following numbers?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a `Dt` table with columns `Dt`, `BusDayOfMonthNum`, `FromEomBusDayOfMonthNum`, `DayType`.

Below is the output:
[image]

I want to make the below update

```
update d
set d.BusDayOfMonthNum = NULL
from Dt d
where Dt = '2018-10-08'

update d
set d.FromEomBusDayOfMonthNum = Null
from Dt d
where Dt = '2018-10-08'
```

But along with that I want to increment the following numbers, so, `BusDayOfMonthNum` for row 9 should be 6 instead of 7 and so on and for `FromEomBusDayOfMonthNum` row 5 should be 18 and so on.

Similarly, with this update

```
update d
set d.DayType = 'B'
from Dt d
where Dt = '2018-11-12'
```

I want to add 8 to row 12 for `BusDayOfMonthNum` and so on and add 14 to row 12 for `FromEomBusDayOfMonthNum` and so on.

Comment: That image is quite difficult to read. Can you get a better one?

Comment: @Nitin Deb: Could you please correct me, Why you want to Update Column "BusDayOfMonth" for row-9 and "FromEomBusDayOfMonthNum" in row-5? Is it the case or you want to update both the columns in same row?

Comment: As part of an update statement you can always add an amount to the existing amount e.g. `update mytable set MyColumn = MyColumn+5 where ...` but it depends how you determine the amount you want to add.

Comment: @TheImpaler - Can you view now?
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1x5-N-bLXlIyyvOnV3eFWnpXybNkJEvTk

Comment: @im_one - Because "BusDayOfMonth" is incrementing and "FromEomBusDayOfMonthNum" is decrementing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have only business days set to 'B' and all other days set to H or W as appropriate, you can calculate the business day of the month (both from start and from end of month) using window functions like this:

```
SELECT
    Dt
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Year(Dt),Month(Dt) ORDER BY Dt) as 'FromMonthStart'
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Year(Dt),Month(Dt) ORDER BY Dt DESC) as 'FromMonthEnd'
FROM
    Dt
WHERE
    DayType = 'B';
```

The Partition By statements in the row_number() window function are to ensure that numbering starts over for each month and year.

You should be able to use that calculation with a merge statement to null/update rows as appropriate:

```
MERGE INTO Dt AS TARGET
USING 
    (SELECT
        Dt
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Year(Dt),Month(Dt) ORDER BY Dt) as 'FromMonthStart'
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Year(Dt),Month(Dt) ORDER BY Dt DESC) as 'FromMonthEnd'
    FROM
        Dt
    WHERE
        DayType = 'B'
    ) AS SOURCE
ON TARGET.Dt = SOURCE.Dt
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE
    SET 
        BusDayOfMonthNum = FromMonthStart
        ,FromEomBusDayOfMonthNum = FromMonthEnd

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN 
    UPDATE
    SET 
        BusDayOfMonthNum = NULL
        ,FromEomBusDayOfMonthNum = NULL

;
```

*I don't have access to a SQL server at the moment to test this (typing MERGE syntax from memory...), so please try this against test data before risking production data.*

Comment: Is there a way to update 11th November as 'B' for the year 2019 along with all the future 11th November till the date which exists in my `Dt` table? My `Dt` table currently has years till 2050 but irrespective of that I want to update `DayType` for all the 11th Novembers from this year to the future dates till the date exists in my `Dt` table.

Comment: To set all November 11 from 2019 on to 'B':
UPDATE Dt SET DayType='B' WHERE YEAR(Dt) >= 2019 AND DAY(Dt) = 11 AND MONTH(Dt) = 11

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand exactly.  How does this seem?

```
update d
set 
d.BusDayOfMonthNum = d.BusDayOfMonthNum -1,
from Dt d
where Dt > '2018-10-08' and Dt<='2018-10-31'

update d
set 
d.FromEomBusDayOfMonthNum = d.FromEomBusDayOfMonthNum +1,
from Dt d
where Dt >= '2018-10-01' and Dt <'2018-10-08'
```

then

```
update d
set d.DayType = 'B', BusDayOfMonthNum =8, FromEomBusDayOfMonthNum =14
from Dt d
where Dt = '2018-11-12'


    update d
    set 
    d.BusDayOfMonthNum = d.BusDayOfMonthNum +1,
    from Dt d
    where Dt > '2018-11-12' and Dt<='2018-11-30'

    update d
    set 
    d.FromEomBusDayOfMonthNum = d.FromEomBusDayOfMonthNum +1,
    from Dt d
    where Dt >= '2018-11-01' and Dt <'2018-11-12'
```